# angular ng-bind using path from string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bind

EDIT: Problem is simple
The bind path comes as string

I want to bind a value from a string (the string is the path to the value)

```
<div ng-init="bigP = 'user.address.street'">
     <div class="whatever" ng-bind="data.bigP"></div>
     OR
     <div class="whatever">{{data.bigP}}</div>
</div>
```

The data I want is `data.user.address.street`. 
It is very important that the result will be something like `{{data.user.address.street}}` or `ng-bind="data.user.address.street"` because infinite recursive structure and I need exact data bindings to work with the rest of the script

Comment: Did you setup your controller correctly? there is so few details in this question. What is the problem? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Everything is working well. Controller etc.
Will I basically need to output a value using a path to it that comes as a string. So normal reference would be: {{data.user.address.street}} but what I have is {{data.bigP}}, where bigP = user.address.street

I've tried anything I could find online but no luck.

Comment: The path to the data that I need to access comes inside the template as a string. I need it to be the exact patch and NOT the ngrepeat path because I need it bound to main scope data. There is a lot else going on on the page, everything is working fine I just need a way to bind using path from string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:

When you have:

```
<script>
$scope.user.address.street = '5th Ave';
</script>
```

And in HTML you have:

```
<div class="whatever" data-path='user.address.street'>{{user.address.street}}</div>
```

Use cases: NG-REPEAT, inline editor etc whatever reason, to change the value in the `$scope` using a `string path` you do:

```
<script>
$parse('user.address.street').assign($scope,'I.Am.New.Value');
$scope.$apply()
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can get it to work by changing string to a list:

```
<div ng-init="bigP = ['user','address','street']">
     <div class="whatever" ng-bind="data[bigP[0]][bigP[1]][bigP[2]]"></div>
     OR
     <div class="whatever">{{data[bigP[0]][bigP[1]][bigP[2]]}}</div>
</div>
```

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwJ6a/25/)**

Comment: the output for this is: [object Object]

Comment: Thanks. Works. But what about infinitely recursive?